# Does there exist an infinite $S \subset \Bbb R^3$ such that any three vectors in $S$ are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exist an infinite subset $S \subset \Bbb R^3$ such that any three vectors in $S$ are linearly independent?